# How do get use for_each here to create lambda functions & their respective docker containers in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, terraform, serverless

I'm working on dynamically creating lambda functions and containers based on the folders that are in my code directory outside of my terraform infra directory, which looks like this:

```
functions/
  function1/
    app.js
    Dockerfile
    package.json
  function2/
    app.js
    Dockerfile
    package.json
  function3/
    app.js
    Dockerfile
    package.json
infra/
  main.tf
  build_lambda.tf
```

All functions are NodeJS lambda functions with the same structure and handler.

My issue is in my infra directory/code. I am trying to use the `terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws module` and the `terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws//modules/docker-build` to create my lambda function and docker container respectively. Below is my code in `main.tf` and `build_lambda.tf`

#### `main.tf`

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.15"
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = ">= 4.63"
    }
    docker = {
      source  = "kreuzwerker/docker"
      version = ">= 3.0"
    }
  }
  backend "s3" {
    encrypt        = true
    bucket         = "my-bucket-for-tfstate"
    key            = "terraform.tfstate"
    region         = "REGION"
  }
}

module "lambda" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws"
  version = "6.0.0"
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

data "aws_ecr_authorization_token" "token" {}

provider "docker" {
  registry_auth {
    address  = "AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.REGION.amazonaws.com"
    username = data.aws_ecr_authorization_token.token.user_name
    password = data.aws_ecr_authorization_token.token.password
  }
}

locals {
  lambda_dirs = [for item in split(",", var.directories) : item if length(item) > 0]
}
```

#### `lambda_build.tf`

```
module "docker_build" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws//modules/docker-build"

  for_each         = toset(local.lambda_dirs)
  create_ecr_repo  = true
  ecr_repo         = each.value
  image_tag        = var.commit_sha
  source_path      = "${path.module}/../functions/${each.value}/"
  docker_file_path = "${path.module}/../functions/${each.value}/Dockerfile"
}

module "lambda_function" {
  source        = "terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws"
  for_each      = toset(local.lambda_dirs)

  function_name = each.value
  description   = "Lambda function for ${each.value}"
  image_uri     = "AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.REGION.amazonaws.com/${each.value}:${var.commit_sha}"
  package_type  = "Image"
  memory_size   = 10000
  timeout       = 900
  role_name     = "${each.value}_role"
  policy_name   = "${each.value}_policy"
  depends_on    = [module.docker_build]
}
```

I am passing the list of directories as an environment variables to terraform via GitHub Actions, but that is getting passed through fine. it is being passed through as something like

`function1,function2,function3`

However, I am getting this error in my tf plan:

```
│ Error: invalid value for name (must match [\w+=,.@-])
│ 
│   with module.lambda.aws_iam_role.lambda[0],
│   on .terraform/modules/lambda/iam.tf line 97, in resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda":
│   97:   name                  = local.role_name
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: invalid value for name (must match [\w+=,.@-])
│ 
│   with module.lambda.aws_iam_policy.logs[0],
│   on .terraform/modules/lambda/iam.tf line 137, in resource "aws_iam_policy" "logs":
│  137:   name   = "${local.policy_name}-logs"
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: External Program Execution Failed
│ 
│   with module.lambda.data.external.archive_prepare[0],
│   on .terraform/modules/lambda/package.tf line 10, in data "external" "archive_prepare":
│   10:   program = [local.python, "${path.module}/package.py", "prepare"]
│ 
│ The data source received an unexpected error while attempting to execute
│ the program.
│ 
│ Program: /usr/bin/python3
│ Error Message: Could not locate source_path "null".  Paths are relative to
│ directory where `terraform plan` is being run
│ ("/home/runner/work/ainchor-news/ainchor-news/infra")
│ 
│ State: exit status 1
```

I have been attempting to hard code variable values from terraform, add a sanitation piece for changing the name just in case, all of that. I want to keep the `for_each` piece in here so that I can dynamically create all of my lambda function instead of writing all of them though.

Comment: I don't know the exact problem, but I am sure that your use of `replace` is wrong.
I am not sure of what are you trying to achieve with `replace("t", "[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]", "_")`, but in order for your regex to be considered as such, you must wrap it in forward slashes (`/your_regex/`). Moreover, if you meant `^` as an anchor to the start of the string you must place it outside the `[`, while if you meant it as the character, you must escape it with `\\^`. Here is the link to the replace function [docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/replace)

Comment: To troubleshoot your errors, you may try to run `terraform console` (passing to it the appropriate var file with `-var-file=<your_varfile>` and inspect the value of `local.lambda_dirs`. Is it what you would expect?
Moreover, as the error suggests the paths are relative to the directory in which you run the `plan`, so the paths should be `${path.module}/functions/...`

Comment: @LorenzoFelletti Yea the array is what I expect. The only thing that might be doing it in  is that there is a trailing comma after the last element in the array, so it looks like `["function1","function2","function3",]`, but according to HCL, it is the same as without that last comma

Comment: I'm starting to think it could be the way the module is being created with terraform in terms of name. When I use for_each here, it creates a module name something like `module.lambda_function["function1"]`. So even though terraform made it that way, it isn't accepting it as a proper name. Question is then, is there a way around this?

Comment: Is the name of your functions really `function1`, because in this case I don't think there is any problem with the name. Otherwise you might need to check if it actually conform to a valid one as per the regex indicated in the error (`[\w+=,.@-]`)

Comment: Would this also include with underscores as well? so if I said module.lambda_function["function_1"], that should still be valid